# Simpify Regular expression for username

Tags: c#, regex

I have quite a complex validation rule for the username and I was hoping someone could help me improve my regex. The rule is:

The user can login with his 15 digit only id

***OR***

Login with his username that follow these rules:

- Can contain greek and english (uppercase and lowercase) characters
- Can contain numbers
- Can contain the symbols: !@#$*_
- Lenght: At least 7. Max 14
- Must contain at least 5 characters (from the english,greek and symbol characters previously stated) and at least 2 numbers

Now here 's the beast I created

```
^\d{15}$|^(?=[a-zA-z0-9\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_]{7,14}$)(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-z\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_].*[a-zA-z\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_].*[a-zA-z\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_].*[a-zA-z\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_].*[a-zA-z\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_]).*
```

While this works I was hoping to get it better. I am writing in C#

Comment: "at least 5 characters and at least 2 numbers": do you mean "at least 5 *letters* and at least 2 *digits*"? Digits and punctuation are characters; "12" is one number not two. (When you want to get a regex right these details are important.)

Comment: Yes you are right. When saying at least 5 characters I mean at least 5 from the [a-zA-Z\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_] character set

Answer (score 3):

I'd split this monster into a series of checks. First three items can be checked with a relatively simple regex, whereas last two items are better done imperatively:

```
if(username.Length < 7 || username.Length > 14) return false;
if(username.CountDigits() < 2) return false;
```

Comment: The key here is to make maintenance easier. A "perfectly optimised" regex is likely to be fragile in the face of ongoing development.

Comment: I do like the approach but that doesn't take into account the fact that the users can either log in with a 15 digit  number or 7-14 length username. I get either a big regex or lots of ifs..

Answer (score 0):

This is a more maintainable version using regexes only, if you are not optimizing for speed:

```
bool valid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d{15}$|^(?=[a-zA-z0-9\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_]{7,14}$)") &&
             Regex.Matches(s, @"\d").Count >= 2 &&
             Regex.Matches(s, @"[a-zA-z\p{IsGreekandCoptic}!@#$*_]").Count >= 5;
```